# Failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource - storyboard and code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have added a TableViewController into my Storyboard, and changed its type to my custom class that inherits UITableViewController.
 I have also added a few cells from the Storyboard into it. (not custom, basic UITableViewCells)
 Now I want to modify these cells programatically (like conditionally adding a disclosure indicator). So I have made my class adopt UITableViewDelegate, but when I try to modify the text of my cell programatically, I get this error:

> NSInternalInconsistencyException : failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

Here is the code :

```
 @interface MyTableViewController () <UITableViewDelegate>
 @end

 @implementation MyTableViewController

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     cell.textLabel.text = @"test";
     return cell;
 }

 @end
```

In my Storyboard, in Referencing Outlets, I correctly have dataSource and delegate linked to the table view.
 What am I missing here? Thanks for your help

Comment: You are calling `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`? That's not the method to call. Call `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"someCellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: For your table view content, are you using Dynamic Prototypes or Static Cells?

Comment: @Larme thank you for your reply. I tried to set in my storyboard the identifier "TestCell" and replaced `cellForRowAtIndexPath` by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, but I get this error now : `unable to dequeue a cell with identifier TestCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard`

Comment: @DavidLari, I'm using static cells

Comment: I "solved" my problem by using `[super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` but I still don't really get what's going on here...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` instead of `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`
But first of all if you're using storyboard or xib you have to set reuseIdentifier there and check if you use the same reuseIdentifier in `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"<your cell id>"];` if you don't use IB you should register your cell by `[self.tableView registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:]`

But pay attention that there are 2 different methods

1.`- (UITableViewCell *)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;`

2.`- (UITableViewCell *)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

if you set not registered reuseIdentifier in 1st you will get a cell == nill and in 2nd you will get a crash
in case if you get it nil you can create and register your new cell using:

```
 if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [UITableViewCell initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:<your cell id>];
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, but I'm still getting the `unable to dequeue a cell with identifier TestCell` error even if I set first my identifier in IB. The app crashes before it checks cell == nil, it crashes on the first line : `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TestCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: @Someday if you call withiout `forIndexPath` thing you will go without crash... but still there is a strange behaviour, did you create a cell in storyboard or separated .xib file?

Comment: if by .xib you have to register it doing following: `[tableView registerNib: [UINib nibWithNibName:@"<Your cell name>" bundle: nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"<Your cell id>"]`

Answer (score -1):

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TxtTableViewCell";
TxtTableViewCell *cell = (TxtTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TxtTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```